# C# Threading still make UI unresponsive

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Well , I have a form1 which has buttons and if you click one of its button 
It would load the UserControl into panel in form1

That usercontrol1 contains a lot of data like Database,charts and picture boxes too. So it would definitely make the User Interface unresponsive while loading.

So I read some article and I found out that I need to run it through another thread so I tried it and it just increase the performance by a little bit.

The usercontrol1 still make the GUI unresponsive for about 3-5 sec and what if my data become larger.

I want to make it responsive and show to user that still loading by running the animated picturebox and stop if its finish loading

here is my code:

```
private void click_dashb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(load_UserControl);
        Thread t = new Thread(pts);
        t.Start();

        //Animated Picturebox to show user that UI is loading
        pictureBox1.Enabled = true;


        hover.Location = new Point(42, 130);
    }


    private void load_UserControl(object state)
    {

        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            //load user control through another thread
            while (panel1.Controls.Count > 0)
                panel1.Controls[0].Dispose();


            Home frm = new Home();


            frm.AutoScroll = true;
            panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
            frm.Show();
        }));

        //Stop the animated GIF means the load is finish!
        pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

If you help me about this problem. I might apply it to all of my works. because most of it contains large data.

Thanks stackoverflow community :)

EDIT:

After reading the comments suggesting to use Background worker . I tried to use it. but still getting a little bit unresponsiveness 
Here's the new code:

```
 private void click_dashb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
 private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {


            BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                while (panel1.Controls.Count > 0)
                    panel1.Controls[0].Dispose();


                Home frm = new Home();


                frm.AutoScroll = true;
                panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
                frm.Show();
            });


        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured while performing operation" + x);
        }

    }

    private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");

        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Operation Completed");


        }
    }
```

It's a little bit better but i still got a little unresponsiveness. Can you check out my code and what's wrong with this.?

thanks again

Comment: Invoke function makes delegate parameter supplied executed in main AKA UI thread.

Comment: There's no point in creating a new thread if that thread is just going to wrap all of its activity in an `Invoke` - the point of `Invoke` is to marshal activity back onto the UI thread.

Comment: Look at BackgroundWorker it's designed specifically to deal with this, you don't need to be creating your own threads.

Comment: Looks like ```while``` is infinity loop here

Comment: So what's is the best option to use here? Is it backgroundworker ? 
Sorry I'm newbie at threading and making ui responsive

Comment: @tym32167 no it's not. The job of loop is to load the userControl to panel  :)

Comment: @MaryJhealynVillena - all of the code you've shown us seems to be intimately UI related - disposing and creating forms, attaching them to panels, etc. If there's a benefit to be realised from non-UI threads here, it's in a portion of code you're not showing us (e.g. if `Home` has a non-trivial constructor, possibly some of the initialization can be moved to a non-UI thread, but there's no way for us to tell you this from what you've shown us)

Comment: If the thing you want to run in a background thread, that takes time, is initializing UI, then you have no recourse but to change that code so that it supports threading or splitting up. UI related code **has** to run on the UI thread. If the code involves loading data from a database, downloading something over the network, building a large and complex data structure, then this can be run in a different thread but if all of that is wrapped inside a UI control then you simply can't do it.

Comment: @Paolo BGW is obsolete, fully replaced by Task.Run and the IProgress<T> interface. In any case, it can't help with heavy UI modifications, which is what the OP asks

Comment: Yes I think using async and Task.Run is the new solution.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks buddy. I get the point. So I should run this through UI related thread. So what should I use. I'm checking the background worker article right now .but still confuse at this new method LOL

Comment: Your first task is to separate GUI and non-GUI code... A good idea anyway but essential to use threading. Only the non-GUI stuff like reading from a Db can be put on another thread.

Comment: @MaryJhealynVillena sorry, didnt get, when this loop ```while (panel1.Controls.Count > 0) panel1.Controls[0].Dispose();``` will break?

Comment: I already update it :) Check the new background worker code. but still got a little unresponsiveness :)

Comment: Where are you removing the controls that you dispose from the controls-collection?

Comment: Using clear() on the control collection instead of a loop with some out of space dispose would be a good start. Then you will take a look into the load Sub of your Home class and you will propaply found a lot of nasty thing (like data loading or something like that) which will certainly load a bunch of events which probably do a lot of nasty thing too. You are searching in the wrong place !

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that although you run the load_UserControl code in a new thread, that code calls Invoke which effectively makes al the code run on the UI thread again. I can image you did that because accessing Forms and PictureBoxes requires running on the UI thread.

The solution (in general) is to do non-UI work on a seperate thread and then switch back to the UI thread to update the visual controls.

To do this, you can conveniently use the BackgroundWorker class. In the DoWork event handler you do the heavy computation, in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler you update the controls. If you want, you can even update some controls (like a progressbar) during the work by means of the ProgressChanged event handler.

Comment: Technically , I have two forms( other one is the userControl)
So where should I apply the background worker? to the Main form or to the user control? 

I was a little bit confuse right now @_@ because I cant get the exact point but I'm having the idea .

right now ' I'm looking for article or any codes to study in able to learn this background worker :( I thought using threading would fix this :( 

Sorry i'm newbie

Comment: Instead of creating a thread explicitely, you use a BackgroundWorker. That object will create a new thread for you nehind the scenes. You only have to provide the DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted event handlers and then kick-off the computation by calling RunWorkerAsync() on the object.

Comment: The example in the BackgroundWorker class documentation on MSDN should get you started.

Comment: I've updated the question and put the new code using background worker. but I still got a little unresponsiveness but it became better than before. 

Check it out thanks

Comment: In the DoWork method you still run everything on UI thread since you still use Invoke or BeginInvoke. If everything you want to do is UI related then using a background thread is impossible. Look for non-UI related code that makes the program slow. Maybe something in the Home constructor? Only creating a Form and changing some Panels should not make your application feel slow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just starting a new thread doesn't make the UI responsive by definition. You need to make the thread so that it actually does stuff in parallel.

Your thread does not, as it basically executes all code in `this.Invoke`.

That being said: Your code *needs* to be executed in `this.Invoke`, as almost everything you do needs to be done on the UI thread.

So in your case, there's really no point in parallelizing stuff, as there's no way to do what you want to do without blocking the UI thread and no technique I know of (Threads, Tasks, BackgroundWorker, etc.) will solve this problem.